# What is the origin of chess clubs?

Tags: history, clubs

In the first pages of Philidor's 1777 edition of *[Analyse du jeu des échecs](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3065686c/f9.item)* (Analysis of chess games) there is a list of subscribers, some of whom are "Members of the Chess Club". They include several Lords and Dukes, etc. and also some Messrs.

Now, I wasn't aware there were chess clubs in the 18th century, and I was wondering when the first chess clubs were created and which were their characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting indeed. Although French, Philidor was in London for some time and virtually all the listed subscribers are clearly English, and book first edition is 1749 when he was there. It appears he played regularly at the St James Chess Club. The English were fond of clubs for a long time.

Here's a Wikipedia article with useful information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois-Andr%C3%A9_Danican_Philidor

And here's a page directly to the point:

https://www.pascalbonenfant.com/18c/clubs/jt_chessclubs.html

As to when the first club started, I have no idea. It's a topic worth researching.